# Laptop keyboard drivers,event handlers in linux

Tags: linux, drivers

Pls explain where are the driver for keyboard & Its handler is located.

Drivers:

By `ls /lib/modules/4.10.0-28-generic/kernel/drivers/input/mouse`-----> gave
All device drivers for mouse is shown (Among that `psmouse.ko` is used in mine).Even if I `sudo rmmod psmouse`, the touchpad is not working yet `usbmouse` is working (as it uses `usbmouse/usbhid`)

So where is my keypad driver in `lsmod`. None in `ls /lib/modules/4.10.0-28-generic/kernel/drivers/input/keyboard` is in lsmod list?

Handlers :

By `cat /proc/bus/input/devices` -----> gave the following

```
SynPS/2 Synatics Touchpad (Handlers : mouse0 event6) 
AT Translated Set 2 Keyboard (Handlers : sysrq,kbd,event4,leds)
```

By `cat /proc/bus/input/handlers` -----> gave the following

```
rfkill,kbd,sysrq,mousedev,evdev,joydev,leds
```

But instead of `mousedev` handler, `mouse0` is used. Why is that so? `mouse0` is available at `/dev/input/mouse0`. Simillary why not `kbd` is available there?

Note: Events are available in `/dev/input` but why not `kbd`?

Answer (score 2):

Quick overview: Mouse and keyboard handling is layered. The most abstract layer on the kernel level is the input event layer (devices `/dev/input/event*`). You can read events on those with `evtest`. Above this are the drivers for X (`evdev`, or lower level drivers) or Wayland (`libinput`). Below this are drivers for USB HID devices (`usbmouse`/`usbhid`), PS/2 keyboards (`kbd`), PS/2 mice (`mousedev`). The mouse devices are a pretty complex zoo, because they also contain now obsolete drivers for serial port mice with different protocols, and other ways to attach mice.

`/dev/input/mouse0` is the *device* for PS/2-level mouse events, while `mousedev` is the *kernel module* that handles it, AFAIK. I don't know why `cat /proc/bus/input/devices` lists device names under "handlers", that's a bit inconsistent.

There is no device for PS/2-level keyboard events by default, but you can create one with the right modules and/or options (I'd have to look this up, as you normally don't need it).

**Bottom line**: Unless you for some reason need to fiddle with lower level protocols (PS/2, serial, USB, HID, ...), just leave them alone. Use the `/dev/input/event*` devices, or use the X or Wayland abstractions.

If you can edit your question with what you actually want to achieve (unless it's pure curiosity), we can give better advice.